# Integration of tailwindcss with wordpress what knowledge required to integrate

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tailwind-css

Can anyone guide me. I am new to wordpress

I have a existing theme which is created using html and tailwindcss. I would like to know how i integrate the theme to wordpress.

Step by step guidance would be helpful. Also I am not very much aware about tailwindcss.

Thanking you in advance!!

Comment: Read https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method specifically :

Add the following code snippet to

> wp-admin/themes/[The name of your template]/functions.php
> of your template

code :

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_head', function () { ?>
<style>
    /* write your CSS code here */
</style>

<!-- or write your html code here -->
<?php } );
```

---

And also with the "Code Snippet" plugin You can do this

---

And also you can put your PHP codes in the functions.php file and your custom CSS codes in the style.css of the child theme.